# When is $f(\operatorname{int}A)=\operatorname{int}f(A)$

Tags: general-topology, functions

We have that [$f:X\rightarrow Y$ is an open map iff $f(\operatorname{int} A)\subseteq \operatorname{int} f(A)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2617025/f-is-open-iff-finta-subset-intfa). My question is: when does it become an equality? Obviously $f$ has to be an open map. The equality will hold if $f$ is a homeomorphism, but can that condition be weakened?

Comment: Sure, it can be weakened. Every homeomorphism onto open image will satisfy this. Also any function between discrete spaces.

Comment: If $X$ is an open proper subset of $Y$, then for every $A \subseteq X$ we have $\iota \left(\text{Int}(A)\right)=\text{Int}\left(\iota(A)\right)$. Note: $\iota$ denotes the inclusion mapping $\iota: X \to Y$. This example should suggest that the desired $f$ need not be surjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f:\mathbb R \rightarrow {a}\ $ is an open map.  Let $A$ be the set of rationals.
$\text{int} f(A) = {a}$;  $f(\text{int} A)$ is empty.
Though $f$ is an open map, $\text{int} f(A)$ is not a subset of $f(\text{int} A)$.

Comment: Seems to be an error in the original post for this question. It should read $f:X \to Y$ is an open map iff $f( \text{Int}(A)) \subseteq f(\text{Int}(A))$. Good catch.

Comment: But @MattAPelto, not all functions are open.

Comment: The comment was supposed to read $f(\text{Int}(A))\subseteq \text{Int}(f(A))$. My apologies for the confusion.

Comment: The edit by YuiTo is incorrect @MattAPelto, and there is no way to @ it to his attention.